# MacBook Pro (Retina, 15", Late 2013) is crashing frequently

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15", Late 2013) is crashing frequently. Specifically, for about five seconds, the screen dims but does not turn off and the backlight on the keys remains on, and then the computer turns off. When I turn the computer on, I have to select the user, enter the password, and login, after which applications start normally. There does not seem to be a pattern to when it will crash. It has crashed less than a minute after restarting, during Internet browsing, and while using R Studio (for statistical analysis). It *seems* to crash more frequently when it is not connected to the power supply, but it also crashes when it is connected to the power supply.

To troubleshoot, I deleted applications that were in preview (Microsoft Office 2016 and R Studio 0.99), updated all applications and deleted one I recently installed (Fantastical), and ensured the operating system was updated to OSX 10.10.2. This didn't work as the MBP crashed soon after, so I then decided to erase the disc and reinstall the operating system. This didn't work, either, as it still crashed multiple times within the first 6 hours of use.

As a result, I brought the computer to a local Apple repair shop, who ran diagnostics, and also erased the disc and then reinstalled the operating system. They found no issues and moreover were unable to reproduce it, which led me to post here. They reported on the invoice that it "passed all AST diagnostics." Apart from bringing it back to the repair shop in order to try to reproduce the issue, I'm not sure what to do to fix the computer. I do wonder if there are logs I could access or if anyhow has an idea about what could be the cause of the computer crashing?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of part of the console log from when it crashed earlier:

[image]

EDIT (Take II): Here are two more screenshots of parts of the console log from when it crashed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next time it happens take note of the time. Then open the Console app located in your Utility folder. Find the time stamp and copy some 10 lines before and 20 after it and paste it here. I assume you do not see Crash reports!

Comment: No crash reports. I will do that.

Comment: Is the following part of a crash report? Apr  8 18:40:16 Joshuas-MacBook-Pro.local ReportCrash[995]: Invoking spindump for pid=973 wakeups_rate=153 duration=295 because of excessive wakeups

Comment: That is another problem, probably waking up during sleep mode. But give me more lines before and after it to see who is doing it.

Comment: Edited the question to include a screenshot of the logs.

Comment: nice work, this might take a while now.

Comment: I would start by determining what is different between ‘home’ and the repair shop. Do you have any external drives or devices that you did not take to the repair shop? If there is, try working without those devices and see if the problem persists. Also consider how you are connected to the internet. If you use WiFi, did the repair shop also test it it with WiFi, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In this log it is the Google Chrome Helper creating havoc.

[image: chrome]

I do not know why, but you can safely kill it for time been.

To do that open your Activity Monitor located in your Utility Folder.

Click on CPU and find Google Chrome Helper.

Use the x in top left to shut it down.

[image: google]

Comment: It crashed twice more this morning; I edited the question to include the logs for both times. Could you let me know if those were also caused by Google Chrome Helper (or something different)?

Comment: Well as soon you use Google Chrome the Helper is also active as shown in the log. Can you use another browser to test.

Comment: Any firmware update that remains to be applied?

Comment: The last 2 reports were not long enough to see a problem other the Google Chrome Helper that might or might not be the problem. Next time post 200 lines before the "bootlog" and please paste as Text file not as png (picture), so I can actually read/search it. Meanwhile please run the Apple Hardware Test, hold the "D key" during boot and use the extended test.